# Compute the minimum input until 0 is entered

Tags: java

My assignment requires us to read in unspecified numbers of integers until the number 0 is entered, which exits the program and prints out the results.

```java
System.out.println("Write a list of integers and type 0 when you are finished");

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int num = 0

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    //user input
    num = in.nextInt();
    // check input for minimum integer
    if (num < min)
        min = num;

} while (num != 0);

System.out.println("The minimum integer is " + min);
```

if I input `[-2,10,15,-1,0]` | output would be `[-2]`

if I input `[6,10,30,0]` | output would be `[0]`, however, my desired output is `[6]`

My problem is that I need it to be able to read negatives and not read 0 as the lowest value.

Comment: `if (num != 0 && num < min) { ... }` - short circuit on checking against 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
if (num < min && num  != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

1. Break at the first moment the user inputs a 0:

```java
  do {
    //user input
    num = in.nextInt();
    // check input for minimum integer
    if(num == 0)
    {
        break; // Goes directly out of the loop
    }
    if (num < min)
        min = num;

}while(num != 0);
```

2. Insert another condition to your second `if` just like @Vic suggested:

```java
  do {
    //user input
    num = in.nextInt();
    // check input for minimum integer
    if(num == 0)
    {
        break; // Goes directly out of the loop
    }
    if (num < min && num != 0)
        min = num;

}while(num != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is take the input directly in the while loop, which will make take the input every time before entering the loop and checke whether it is 0 or not immidiately.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Write a list of integers and type 0 when you are finished");

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int num;
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while ((num = in.nextInt()) != 0) {
        //user input
        //num = in.nextInt();
        // check input for minimum integer
        if (num < min)
            min = num;
    
    } 
    
    System.out.println("The minimum integer is " + min);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another recommendation  change 0 to exit to Q to exit, As someone can input 0 as a number.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this,

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int num = 0;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while ((num = in.nextInt()) != 0) {
    if (num < min) min = num;
}
```